# Creating a ServiceDefinition.csdef

Tags: c#, azure

I'm new to VS and Azure, I've created an application in VS15 and have deployed it to Azure, the application was not created as a cloud app. 
I need to deploy Crystal Reports for Visual Studio runtime, I've followed the example here http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html
I'm supposed to edit my ServiceDefinition.csdef file like this

`<WebRole name="Web" vmsize="Small">
  ...
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="StartUp.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
  </Startup>
</WebRole>`

The problem is there is no ServiceDefinition.csdef in my project, should it have been created with the project / build?
How do I create one and where in the project is it supposed to be created?

Thanks

Comment: Is your application deployed as Website (WebApp), Cloud Service or VM hosted application? Look at [comparison](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/) to get more details.
ServiceDefinition.csdef is a part of cspkg for Cloud Services.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `csdef` file will not solve your problem. What you would need to do is convert your web application into a Cloud Service project. When you convert it, a new cloud services project will be added to your solution and all the necessary files (cscfg, csdef, WebRole.cs) will be added to your projects appropriately.

To convert your project, simply `right click the project --> Convert --> Convert to Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project` as shown in picture below.

[image]

However please keep in mind that Cloud Services are deployed in a different manner than your regular web applications and you will lose some of the features (like ultra fast deployment) that you currently have with web applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I needed

Comment: In my visual studio both vs2015 and vs2019, the convert button is not showing up. what can I do?

Comment: I can't see the convert button as well